# MenuItem that can Show Both .png and Vector Based Images from a Resource URI Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icons

I have the following `MenuItem` style in a resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:GambitFramework.Modules.MainMenu.Controls"
                    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:GambitFramework.Core.Converters"
                    xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:GambitFramework.Modules.MainMenu.Behaviors">
    <Converters:NullableValueConverter x:Key="NullableValueConverter"/>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Image x:Key="MenuItemIcon" 
             x:Shared="false" 
             Source="{Binding IconSource, Converter={StaticResource NullableValueConverter}}"/>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}"/>
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
        <Setter Property="Behaviors:MenuBehavior.UpdateCommandUiItems" Value="True"/>
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Text}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This works for .png resource type, where my `IconSource` property might be something like

```
public override Uri IconSource
{
    get { return new Uri("pack://application:,,,/GambitFramework;component/Resources/Icons/Undo.png"); }
}
```

Now, I have a large library of vector graphics icon avalible to me an I would like to add the ability to specify either a URI to a .png OR some vector graphic resource specified in a resource dictionary, something like

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="resources_icons_xaml"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Canvas x:Key="appbar_acorn" Width="48" Height="48" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 48,0L 48,48L 0,48L 0,0">
        <Path Width="22.3248" Height="25.8518" Canvas.Left="13.6757" Canvas.Top="11.4012" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackBrush}" Data="F1 M 16.6309,18.6563C 17.1309,8.15625 29.8809,14.1563 29.8809,14.1563C 30.8809,11.1563 34.1308,11.4063 34.1308,11.4063C 33.5,12 34.6309,13.1563 34.6309,13.1563C 32.1309,13.1562 31.1309,14.9062 31.1309,14.9062C 41.1309,23.9062 32.6309,27.9063 32.6309,27.9062C 24.6309,24.9063 21.1309,22.1562 16.6309,18.6563 Z M 16.6309,19.9063C 21.6309,24.1563 25.1309,26.1562 31.6309,28.6562C 31.6309,28.6562 26.3809,39.1562 18.3809,36.1563C 18.3809,36.1563 18,38 16.3809,36.9063C 15,36 16.3809,34.9063 16.3809,34.9063C 16.3809,34.9063 10.1309,30.9062 16.6309,19.9063 Z "/>
    </Canvas>
    ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I modify my `MenuItem` style so that I can use BOTH a URI to a .png and a URI to a vector graphic?

I am mainly interested how in the XAML I can differentiate and display the resource in the appropriate way, I have never seen this done and I am confused over how to go about it.

Thanks for your time.

---

In a previous version of the system I only had vector graphic support and my XAML for the `MenuItem` style was

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Caliburn="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
                    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:GambitFramework.Core.Converters"
                    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:GambitFramework.Modules.MainMenu.Controls">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Converters:StringToResourceConverter x:Key="StringToResourceDictionary"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Rectangle x:Key="MenuItemIcon" x:Shared="False" 
               Visibility="{Binding IconVisibility}"
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Width="16" Height="16">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" Visual="{Binding IconSource}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemIcon}"/> 
        <Setter Property="InputGestureText" Value="{Binding InputGestureText}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Action.Target" Value="{Binding}"/>
        <Setter Property="Caliburn:Message.Attach" Value="{Binding ActionText}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CheckableMenuItem" 
           TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MenuItemEx}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
    </Style>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="MenuTemplate" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=Text}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

where the binding source was

```
public Canvas IconSource
{
    get { return iconSource; }
    set
    {
        iconSource = value;
        IconVisibility = iconSource == null ?
            Visibility.Collapsed :
            Visibility.Visible;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IconSource);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can apply something like [this from an old post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292179/best-way-to-use-a-vector-image-in-wpf/13293017#13293017) and that way drop in whatever you want, and even pass in dependency properties to alter things like a Path Fill for different colors etc on the fly. Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I want to be able to display BOTH .png images AND vector based images. This just works for vector based images or have I missed something?

Comment: It works for whatever you could ever want to throw in there. If you're going by that example, the part that says "Paste your xaml here" can be whatever you want it to be. It could be an image, a Path, a bunch of controls, another view, just about whatever. Then if you wanted it more dynamic, you do a TemplateBinding for like the Data= or the Src= or whatever to a property like `Tag` and pass in any resource, or string, or whatever you want.

Comment: But it is exactly the XAML that is missing that is the crux of the issue. I can _either_ have an `<Image ...>` in which case I would use a URI to a .png, _or_ a `<Rectangle ...>` with a `<Rectangle.Fill>` as a `<VisualBrush ...>` but I can have both. Again, I might be missing something, but if you could provide a brief example it would be most appreciated and I will happily award some rep! Thanks again for your time. All the best...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to model your classes a little better. There is no "URI" to a vector graphic.

Start wih this:

```
public abstract class IconPresentation{}
public sealed class ImageIconPresentation : IconPresentation
{
    private readonly string _url;

    public Uri IconSource
    {
        get { return new Uri(_url); }
    }

    public ImageIconPresentation(string url){
        _url = url;
    }
}

public sealed class ResourceIconPresentation : IconPresentation
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ResourceIconPresentation(string name){
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

After this is done, you'll have to modify the template of `Icon`:

```
<Setter Property="Icon"> 
 <Setter.Value>
   <ContentControl Content="{Binding Icon}"/>
 </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Now you just need to declare buch of `DataTemplate` for each icon presentation.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ImageIconPresentation}">
  <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ResourceIconPresentation}">
    <Rectangle ..>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" 
               Visual="{ext:ResourceKeyBinding Path=Name}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</DataTemplate>
```

And that's it!

Your viewmodel would have property as so:

```
public IconPresentation Icon { get; private set; }
```

ps, I used "StaticResource key binding", which is not available by default. It can be found from here: [Is it possible to dynamically create a ResourceKey for a StaticResource? (eg using a Binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262037/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-a-resourcekey-for-a-staticresource-eg-usi)

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, it is most appreciated. I will look to implement this now...

Comment: This does not seem to work. Have you implemented something similar?

Comment: The binding to my `Icon` which I made of interface type `IIconPresentation` (which I inherited by the other two classes) does not work, it does not fail, it just does not appear at all for the ContentPresenter when inspected with Snoop. Any ideas?

Comment: @Killercam: the data binding engine does not work with interfaces. YOu really oughta have the one I posted (abstract class) ;).

Comment: Oh my god, why do I do these things. Obviously... Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, sorry to trouble you but this solution is still not working for me. I have cobbled together a test solution using buttons in a list view, but the images are not being rendered. Would you be so kind as to take a quick look? I will provide some rep if required! :] http://1drv.ms/1yE0i25

Comment: @Killercam: Icons not showing is your smallest problem :p. Even the text for first item is not showing. First problem I see is `Button` style setting `Content` property which won't work. `Content` is shared between various elements, and can't appear in same place twice. You want `Template` property instead. If you didn't understand what I said, you can create new thread that demostrates this problem (even `TextBlock` not working).

Comment: And secondly, this specific `ResourceKeyBinding` extension I gave you, is too weak for your use case. It doesn't work well when used within `VisualBrush` element. It can be improved & fixed. You can attempt yourself to fix it, or I'll give you few more pointers about it. Though, you're almost there.

Comment: I have done this. Thanks. You actually don't need the `ResourceKeyBindingExtension` class at all. Anyway, I appreciate your time, all the best.