# How to bind to XAML resource color from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have trouble with binding the color from code behind to a color defined as resource in XAML.
The binding works fine for the text (aka Message), but I cannot get it done for the colors defined in XAML.
Here is the stripped down code, that I'm using.

The  **XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
 <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueBrush" Color="#FFCFEDFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenBrush" Color="#FFE5EFC8" />
 </Window.Resources>

 <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List, ElementName=UI}" x:Name="listBox" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.Background>
>>>                         <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource {Binding Path=Background}}"/>    <<< Here is my problem <<<
                        </Grid.Background>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                 </Grid>
             </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     </ListBox>
 </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Line> buffer;   

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            buffer = new ObservableCollection<Line>();

            listBox.ItemsSource = buffer;
            buffer.Add(new Line("Line1", "BlueBrush"));
            buffer.Add(new Line("Line2", "GreenBrush"));
        }

        public class Line
        {
            private string _message;
            private string _background;

            public Line(String message, String background)
            {
                this._message = message;
                this._background = background;
            }

            public string Message
            {
                get { return _message; }
                set { _message = value; }
            }

            public string Background
            {
                get { return _background; }
                set { _background = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13262037/1136211

Comment: I have seen this post before, but it is about dynamicaly creating resources. That is a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Just bind your `Background` to a `Brush` Property.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding List, ElementName=UI}" x:Name="listBox" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{Binding Background}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

And Change Your `String` Property to `Brush`.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                buffer = new ObservableCollection<Line>();

                listBox.ItemsSource = buffer;
                buffer.Add(new Line("Line1", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue)));
                buffer.Add(new Line("Line2", new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)));
            }
            private ObservableCollection<Line> buffer;   

            public class Line
            {
                private string _message;
                private Brush _background;

                public Line(String message, Brush background)
                {
                    this._message = message;
                    this._background = background;
                }

                public string Message
                {
                    get { return _message; }
                    set { _message = value; }
                }

                public Brush Background
                {
                    get { return _background; }
                    set { _background = value; }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I actually wante to have the brushed predefined somewhere and not to create the new for each line. Because I don't want to reduce the performance.

Comment: @thowa You don't need to create a new SolidColorBrush for each Line. Instead reuse Brush instances. When two Lines should have the same color, assign the same SolidColorBrush instance to their Background property. Besides that, you could still define them as resource and accees them in code behind by `(Brush)Resources["BlueBrush"]`. Referencing a Brush instance by a view model property doesn't cost more than holding a string for its resource key.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Property called `BackgroundBrush` and use this code to cast your string to brush:

```
public Brush BackgroundBrush => return (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(this.Background);
```

Bind to it using only binding keyword (no need to StaticResource):

```
{Binding BackgroundBrush}
```